# How do I turn off the discrete card on boot when there's no option in the BIOS?

Tags: hybrid-graphics

I have quite old laptop - MSI CX620MX. It has two graphic cards - integrated Intel card and ATI Mobility Radeon HD545v.

I have installed WIN7 and ubuntu 12.04. I would like to know, how can I disable the discrete card on bot up so that laptop saves me energy and the processor wouldn't be running all the time at about 65 - 70 degrees.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On ubuntu, try add this two lines into /etc/rc.local file before exit 0:

`echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

`echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

Save the file and check your cards:

`cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

**Source:** http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-12-04-turn-off-discrete-graphic-card-on-boot