# How do I disable the discrete graphics and force the use of my integrated Intel HD graphics on an HP Envy 15t-3200?

Tags: intel-graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics

I have been trying to blacklist my open source AMD Radeon driver so that my system will use only the Intel HD 4000 Ivy bridge graphics. What is the proper procedure? I am using `xserver-xorg-video-ati`, currently.

The settings in the BIOS of my HP Envy 15t-3200 machine does not show any configuration option for disabling the discrete graphics card, unfortunately, so I'm looking for a way to do this in the OS.

- The BIOS on my laptop (HP Envy 15t-3200) does not have a BIOS option for disabling, or choosing, which adapter I'd like to use exclusively.
- vgaswitcheroo [does not apply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217467/how-do-i-disable-discrete-graphics) to my hardware configuration.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the discrete graphics in your system's BIOS? And possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217467/disable-discrete-graphics

Comment: Note:  The BIOS on my laptop (HP Envy 15t-3200) does not have a BIOS option for disabling, or choosing, which adapter I'd like to use exclusively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 hybrid graphics turn off discrete card on boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166682/ubuntu-12-04-hybrid-graphics-turn-off-discrete-card-on-boot)

Comment: Tom, vgaswitcheroo does not apply to my hardware configuration.  At the time of this writing this question has only gotten 14 views.  May we please allow for it to reach a more varied audiance before it is voted as closed?

Comment: You need to put that kind of info in the question (I've added it in), otherwise it just reads like a duplicate to reviewers.

Answer (score 2):

`vgaswitcheroo` applies if there is a free driver from linux kernel and kernel modesetting is activated. So it should work if there is no fgrlx installed. I made my Sony VPCSA with similar setup (Intel 4000, Radeon 6600M) working.

I replaced a line in `/etc/defalut/grub` (1):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video.allow_duplicates=1 radeon.modeset=1"
```

It fixed the problem for Ubuntu 12.10. However, that's not enough for Debian/unstable.
In addition, I had to add a line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (2):

```
blacklist radeon
```

And to `/etc/rc.local` BEFORE `exit 0;` (3):

```
modprobe radeon modeset=1
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug/
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

If you have issues, start with (2). It has reliably resulted in a bootable system, than proceed with (3).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this issue also wasn't resolved on other operating systems (Windows) - so seems like this is hardware issue rather than software.

Upd: here is some additional info http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video-e-g-Windows-8/HP-Envy-17-3D-CTO-3200-HD-4000-graphics-WiDi-locked-out-of/td-p/1630785

and http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/hp-envy-17t-3200/4864-3121_7-35328488.html